# How to add new items to an existing menu in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I want to add a new item to a menu. For example

> File > New > **New item**

or

> Project > Build > Working set > **New item**

I've got this far with my plugin.xml:

```
<menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="i don't know id">
         <command
               commandId="testcommand"
               icon="icons/menu_icon01.jpg"
               label="test"
               style="push">
         </command>
</menuContribution>
```

How can I find out the IDs of existing commands in Eclipse menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you view your `menuContribution` in the editor, you can add a new command and click *browse* next to the commandId in the Extension Element Details. You'll get a list of all possible comands (at least in my Juno Version).

If you are looking for a specific item, Alt+Shift+F2, then click on the menu entry you want to inspect.

The menu File -> New however consists of Wizards. You can add to that using the org.eclipse.ui.newWizards extension point and pointing it to your `Wizard` implementation.